# 1000 marbles in a line winning strategy

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

There is an infinite grid. Two players play a game. Player A places two black marbles in consecutive blocks in his turn, and player B places one white marble in any of the squares. Player A wins, if he gets 1000 black marbles together in a line. However, player B does not have any winning combination, that is even if 1000 whites occur in a row, player B does not win. Show that player A always has a winning strategy.

Comment: Can you suggest a field to which this question might be related ?

Comment: I don't really understand the game. If we have an infinite grid, the probability to have a winning grid is very small!?

Comment: Can you structure your question a way it will be easier to understand it.

Comment: My intuition: It takes player B two moves to block one of A's potential lines, while A can create many potential lines at once (for example, his first move starts 3 potential lines).  I guess we need to show that A can continue to grow his potential lines and start new potential lines much faster than B can block them.

Comment: For clarification, is the grid specifically two-dimensional? by "consecutive blocks" do you mean to say two orthogonally adjacent blocks?  And finally, "1000 in a line" do you mean to be 1000 orthogonally adjacent blocks?

Comment: @JMoravitz - Yes, the grid is two dimensional. By consecutive blocks, I mean that two black balls are added to two orthogonal squares (either vertically or horizontally).  1000 in a line, thus means that 1000 black balls in a line, horizontally or vertically.